# Difference between Extensions and Extra properties in Gradle

Tags: gradle

According to [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware.html), the `ExtensionAware` objects can be extended at runtime with other objects.

So we can create

```
// Add new extensions via the extension container
project.extensions.create('custom', String, "bar")
```

and then can access it as

```
project.custom == "bar"
```

Then, we have [Extra properties extensions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html) that allow new properties to be added to existing objects.

```
project.ext.custom = "bar"
```

or simply

```
project.custom = "bar"
```

It seems there is no difference between the two from the usability point of view.

I understand `ext` is a special extension and the scope for searching properties is different from other extensions, but what is a practical difference between the two? Do simple extensions and ext provide the same functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, both *extensions* and *extra properties* serve the same purpose, as they both help to extend the scope of various elements in the Gradle DSL, mainly the `Project` object. The [documentation on `Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) introduces the functionalities with the following explanation:

> - The *extra* properties of the project. Each project maintains a map of extra properties, which can contain any arbitrary name -> value pair. Once defined, the properties of this scope are **readable and writable**. See extra properties for more details.
> - The *extensions* added to the project **by the plugins**. Each extension is available as a **read-only** property with the same name as the extension.

I highlighted some parts of the documentation extract above to show two exemplary differences between the features:

1. While *extra properties* can be both read and written after definition, an *extension* is read-only once it is defined. If the extension is a complex object, its child properties may be written, but not the extension itself.
2. *Extensions* are mainly for plugin developers, while *extra properties* should be used inside the actual build script.

Comment: "Each extension is available as a read-only property" is the point I was missing. I wonder why this is not mentioned in Gradle docs but in API docs. Thanks for answering.